# Displaying Google Tango scans with Hololens

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango, hololens

I am currently working with Google Tango and Microsoft Hololens. I got the idea of scanning a room or an object using google Tango and then converting and showing it as hologram with the Hololens.

For that I need to get the ADF file on my computer.

Does someone know of a way to import adf-files onto a computer?
Do you know if it is possible to convert adf-files into usable 3d files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ADF is not a 3D scan of the room, it's a collection of feature descriptors from the computer vision algorithms with associated positional data, but the format is not documented.

You will want to use the point cloud from the depth sensor, convert it to a mesh (there are existing apps to do this) and import the mesh into a render engine on Hololens.